# Key Annotation in Model Class - C#

Tags: c#, key, data-annotations

I'm having a Model Class to construct Person

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
}
```

Shall we use the `[Key]` annotation for this normal model Class? If Yes, whats the Pros and Cons. Kindly assist me in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pros and cons, it depends on your choice and the situation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

> By convention, a property named **Id** or **Id** will be configured
>   as the key of an entity.

By convection, there is no need to use `Key` attribute. But imagine you already have a table which its primary key name is `SomeRandomKey`, in this situation the `Key` attribute is useful.

Comment: For EF we can add the `[Key]`. But in simple model class its good approach?

Comment: I think there is not anything wrong with it. It's meaningful and I think yes it's good.